# laravel redirect other page if data is invalid

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i am a beginner of laravel.

**i want to redirect other page if form data is invalid**.

here is my controller's code :

```
public function register(Request $request)    {
     $this->validation($request);
     User::create($request->all());
     return $request->all();
}

public function validation($request)    {
      $validatedData = $request->validate([
       'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
       'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
       'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email',
       'password' => 'required|min:6',
       'confirm_password' =>'required|min:6|same:password',
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a vailidator

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all() , [
    'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
    'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
    'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users,email',
    'password' => 'required|min:6',
    'confirm_password' =>'required|min:6|same:password',
])
```

And then check if it fails and perform a redirect

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect('your/other/page/url')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
}
```

A more detailed description can be found here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#manually-creating-validators

Comment: i see this error :- `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'kingb58616@gmail.com' for key 'users_email_unique' (SQL: insert into `users` (`first_name`, `last_name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (istiaq, nirab, kingb58616@gmail.com, 12345678, 2019-01-17 11:16:26, 2019-01-17 11:16:26))`

Comment: It seems the email adress 'kingb58616@gmail.com' already exists in your table and the table is configured to not allow duplicate entry's. Are you inserting data before you do the validation ?

Comment: thanks mike ....i understand & solved my problems ....i put it into `register` function & delete `validation ` function .